# Unable to get correct date T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The stored procedure below is suppose to get the `OrderCompletionDate` year as last year AND and adds a month to current month.

So if I run it in January of 2018, it returns data for February 2017, and in February 2018, it will return the data from March 2017, so on and so forth.

***My error:***

When we get to December, it looks for month 13, which does not exist. I want it to get the current year's January data in this case. So when we get to December 2018, it should return the January 2018 data.

**My question is:**

How can I change this stored procedure so it still returns the last year and month +1 data. But when we get to December, it returns data for January of the current year?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetAnniversaryCustomers]
    @date DATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        BAN_ADSL_TN,
        REPLACE(LandlinePhoneNumber, ',', '') LandlinePhoneNumber,
        REPLACE(MobilePhoneNumber, ',', '') MobilePhoneNumber,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        REPLACE(ServiceAddress, ',', '') ServiceAddress,
        ServiceAddressAptNo,
        REPLACE(ServiceAddressCity, ',', '') ServiceAddressCity,
        ServiceAddressState,
        ServiceAddressZip,
        OrderCompletionDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderCompletionDate, 101)
    FROM 
        dbo.Customers 
    WHERE 
        StatusID = 115 AND 
        YEAR(OrderCompletionDate) = YEAR(@date) - 1 AND 
        MONTH(OrderCompletionDate) = MONTH(@date) + 1
    ORDER BY 
        OrderCompletionDate DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE
        StatusID = 115
    AND OrderCompletionDate >= DATEADD(month, -11, @date)
    AND OrderCompletionDate <  DATEADD(month, -10, @date)
```

By using `DATEADD()` all the boundary cases are handled for you.

By using `>= startDate AND < endDate` you make the use of `DATEADD()` even simpler.

By putting all the calculations on the right hand side *(manipulating the variable, not the table's data)* you improve performance and enable use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetAnniversaryCustomers]
 @date DATE
 AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @HistoricalDate DATE = DATEADD(month,-11,@date);
DECLARE @HistoricalDateStart DATE = DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,@HistoricalDate),0);
DECLARE @HistoricalDateEnd DATE = DATEADD(month,1,@HistoricalDateStart);


SELECT  CustomerID,
    BAN_ADSL_TN,
    REPLACE(LandlinePhoneNumber,',','')LandlinePhoneNumber,
    REPLACE(MobilePhoneNumber,',','')MobilePhoneNumber,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    REPLACE(ServiceAddress,',','')ServiceAddress,
    ServiceAddressAptNo,
    REPLACE(ServiceAddressCity,',','')ServiceAddressCity,
    ServiceAddressState,
    ServiceAddressZip,
    --MailingAddress,
    --MailingAddressAptNo,
    --MailingAddressCity,
    --MailingAddressState,
    --MailingAddressZip,
    --LanguageID,
    --Customer Service Number 
    OrderCompletionDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderCompletionDate, 101)
 FROM dbo.Customers 
 WHERE StatusID = 115
    AND OrderCompletionDate >= @HistoricalDateStart
    AND OrderCompletionDate < @HistoricalDateEnd
    ORDER BY OrderCompletionDate DESC
```